# Creating a template inner lambda function?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, functional-programming

I been trying to solve the next functional problem in C++:

```
template <typename T>
auto createFunction(T& ClosuredData) {
    template <typename U>
    return [&](function<void(T&, U&)> Callback) {
        return [&](U& DataFromCallback) {
            Callback(ClosuredData, DataFromCallback);
        };
    };
};

// example use
struct Person {
   string name{"Foo"};
   int age = 20;
}
Person foo{};
auto mutate = createFunction(foo);
auto changeAge = mutate<int>([](Person& person, int& age) {
    person.age = age;
})

changeAge(20)
```

So basically a template Function creator with an inner template lambda.
But of course as far as I know inner templates are not possible in C++.
I tried to make the callback as an auto type, but of course that way I can't infer the `DataFromCallback` resulting in false type-safety.

Can I somehow achieve a proper type safety without introducing a class/struct?

Edit:
One of the "solution" I seen is using an auto type instead of a functional:

```
template <typename T>
auto CreateFunction(T& ClosuredData) {
    return [&](auto Callback) {
        return [&, Callback](auto DataFromCallback) {
            Callback(ClosuredData, DataFromCallback);
        };
    };
};
```

This is really cool, but gives a false sense of typesafety, for example:

```
{
    Person person{};
    auto personMutator = CreateFunction(person);
    auto changeAge = personMutator([](Person& person, int age) {
        person.age = age;
    });

    changeAge(""); // Would not throw an error in this line, but at an upper stack

    changeAge(any); // same stuff
}
```

Comment: Even if you create such a lambda (it's doable with the new C++20 syntax), `mutate<int>(params)` isn't going to work. You'd have to call it with `mutate.operator()<int>(params)`, OR cast the argument to `std::function`.

Comment: Why is it so important to not introduce a struct/class name? It would make your code *far* more readable, since people can actually track down typenames and figure out what's going on.

Comment: it's not that important, I just wanna see if it's possible. quite a fan of functional programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you could use generic lambdas available since C++14 (which basically work as inner templates):

```
template <typename T>
auto CreateFunction(T& ClosuredData) {
    return [&](auto Callback) {
        return [&, Callback](auto DataFromCallback) {
            Callback(ClosuredData, DataFromCallback);
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: That something I actually did, but gave a false sense of type safety as I am not able to infer the DataFromCallback from the Callback :/.

Comment: @IstvanOrban What do you mean by "I am not able to infer the DataFromCallback from the Callback"?

Comment: So basically, if I would to create something like: (sorry can't format the next line of codes...)

{
    Person person{};
    auto personMutator = CreateFunction(person);
    auto changeAge = personMutator([](Person& person, int age) {
        person.age = age;
    });
}
my changeAge would accept any arguments. For example:

changeAge("string") // this line wouldn't throw any error, of course still would not compile

changeAge(123) // same thing

Comment: I guess you should provide mcve (with link to online compiler). `changeAge("string")` should cause compile time error.

Comment: yeah it would cause, but not the line itself. So the call (changeAge(any)) itself would be totally valid. The error would come from a different stack.

Comment: added some edits about my concern. anyway this one is the closes for the use case I want to implement

Comment: @IstvanOrban I don't see how the described behavior can be possible. Something like `changeAge("string")` should definitely trigger a template instantiation error. mcve or it did not happen...